# Get particles.js on the correct layer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, particles.js

I can't make [particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) work as a background. It covers the entire page, I've tried setting a higher z-index (50) for everything I want to cover particles.js with. Here's the [particles codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpJjGG). The codepen has no background, therefor the particles are not visible.

The code below is what I'm trying to set as background for `<section id="services">`.

```
<!-- particles.js container --> 
<div id="particles-js"></div> 
<!-- stats - count particles --> 
<!-- particles.js lib - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js --> 
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script> 
<!-- stats.js lib --> <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that it covers everything inside `<section>` as well, not sure why.

The code you're about to see is nothing but a butchered ole' bootstrap template. Never intended to make any real use of it in the first place, hence the confusing amount of style attributes.

```
<section id="services" style="padding:10px;background-color:black;">
<!-- Here's where I thought fitting it would cause it to work as a background -->
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:10px;margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="row text-center" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
            <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;max-width:720px;width:100%;">
                <button id="reload" onclick="return returnGame();clearDescr();">
                    <div class="notspinning" id="theSpinner"></div>
                </button>
                <span id="findMe">
                    <a href="" id="steamLink" style="color:#333" target="_blank">
                        <h4 class="service-heading" id="gameName" style="font-family:Montserrat,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight: 700;font-size: 22px;color:#777;"></h4>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <p class="text-muted" id="gameDescr" style="min-height:100px;font-family:MyWebFont;"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any sort of guidance just in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried setting an element as the background, e.g. `position: fixed; top:0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 0` and then another div for your content `position: relative`?

e.g. http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/rebroK

In its simplest form your markup would look like:

```
<style>
    #particle {
      background-color: #b61924;
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      z-index:0; 
    }
    #overlay {
      position:relative;
    }
</style>
<div id="particle"></div>
<div id="overylay">[Your content here]</div>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {};
    particlesJS("particle", options); 
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried similar solutions, but I've come to terms with the fact that the entire scribbled excuse of a website is the problem. This fixes one problem, breaks another. I'll just have to do things properly if I wanna make use of this. Thanks though!

Comment: Correct is good! But also have you tried making your `.container` `position:relative;`?